# What is the address of entry point of a file linked by gnu linker?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, ld

I've created a small multiboot complaint kernel that I, until now, used to boot with grub. Now I  want to create my own bootloader for it. But I don't know at what address the gnu linker places entry point program. In Microsoft's PE files, there was a specific field called AddressofEntryPoint in _IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER. Is there any such way to find AddressofEntryPoint of a kernel linked by gnu linker (ld)?

Comment: [ELF also has an entry point field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_layout) `e_entry` _This is the memory address of the entry point from where the process starts executing._ If you don't use ELF then of course you have the multiboot header which again has an entry point field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the binary format you use. For ELF, the `e_entry` member of the main header is what you want.